# Problem‎ with redefining \chapter{...} command‎

Tags: macros, header-footer, page-numbering, chapters

I want to change the definition of `\chapter[...]{...}` ‎to‎ `\chapter[...]{...‎}‎‎‎\thispagestyle{empty}`‎‎.‎ To do this, I'm using the code ‎below:‎

```
\documentclass{book}
\let\origchapter\chapter
\renewcommand{\chapter}[2][]{%
\origchapter[#1]{#2}
\thispagestyle{empty}
}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{Bla Bla}
Some text ...
\newpage
\chapter{Bla Bla}
\end{document}
```

‎Everything is ok, but when I call ‎`\tableofcontents‎` after the ‎‎`\begin{‎document}`‎‎‎,‎ ‎I'll‎ get the following error:‎

```
! LaTeX Error: Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item.‎‎
```

What‎ am I ‎‎doing wrong‎?‎

Comment: If you do not need page style `plain`, then `\makeatletter\let\ps@plain\ps@empty` can help.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Addition to Werner's answer.

### Unknown `\chapter`

The definition of `\chapter` might not contain `\thispagestyle{empty}`, because
it is hidden in later called macros or this action looks different. Then the patching
as in Werner's answer will fail, because `{plain}` is missing in the definition text of `\chapter`. Therefore the following example provides a generic solution, it redefines `\chapter` with support of the star form and the optional argument:

```
\documentclass{report}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\saved@chapter}{}
\let\saved@chapter\chapter
\renewcommand*{\chapter}{%
  \begingroup
  \toks@{\endgroup\saved@chapter}%
  \@ifstar{%
    \toks@\expandafter{\the\toks@*}%
    \final@chapter
  }{\next@chapter}%
}
\newcommand*{\final@chapter}[1]{%
  \the\toks@{#1}%
  \thispagestyle{empty}%
}
\newcommand*{\next@chapter}{%
  \@ifnextchar[{\opt@chapter}{\final@chapter}%
}
\newcommand*{\opt@chapter}{}
\def\opt@chapter[#1]{%
  \toks@\expandafter{\the\toks@[{#1}]}%
  \final@chapter
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter*{Chapter with star}
\chapter{Chapter without optional argument}
\chapter[Chapter's optional argument]{Chapter with optional argument}
\end{document}
```

### `KOMA-Script`

The `KOMA-Script` classes uses the following definition for `\chapter`:

```
\newcommand\chapter{\if@openright\cleardoublepage\else\clearpage\fi
  \thispagestyle{\chapterpagestyle}%
  \global\@topnum\z@
  \@afterindentfalse
  \secdef\@chapter\@schapter
}
```

It misses `plain`, because it is replaced by `\chapterpagestyle`. However, this macro can be redefined, no need for redefining `\chapter`:

```
\renewcommand*{\chapterpagestyle}{empty}
```

### Class `memoir`

Chapters in `memoir` support a special page style `chapter`:

```
\newcommand\chapter{%
  \ifartopt\par\@nameuse{chapterblock}\else
    \clearforchapter
    \thispagestyle{chapter}
    \global\@topnum\z@
  \fi
  \m@mindentafterchapter
  \@ifstar{\@m@mschapter}{\@m@mchapter}}
```

The page style can be changed by `\aliaspagestyle`:

```
\aliaspagestyle{chapter}{empty}
```

### Full example

The following example catches five cases:

- `\chapter` is not available.
- Class `memoir`.
- `KOMA-Script` classes.
- Patching via `etoolbox`'s `\patchcmd` (see Werner's answer).
- Generic redefinition of `\chapter`.

The code:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}

\makeatletter
\begingroup\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\endgroup
\expandafter\ifx\csname chapter\endcsname\relax
  \wlog{* No \string\chapter.}%
\else
  \@ifclassloaded{memoir}{%
    % Class memoir
    \aliaspagestyle{chapter}{empty}%
    \wlog{* Chapter page style redefined via \string\aliaspagestyle.}%
  }{%
    \begingroup\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\endgroup
    \expandafter\ifx\csname chapterpagestyle\endcsname\relax
      % Patching with etoolbox
      \RequirePackage{etoolbox}[2010/09/12]%
      \patchcmd{\chapter}{plain}{empty}{%
        \wlog{* Chapter patched by \string\patchcmd.}%
      }{%
        % Generic case
        \newcommand*{\saved@chapter}{}%
        \let\saved@chapter\chapter
        \renewcommand*{\chapter}{%
          \begingroup
          \toks@{\endgroup\saved@chapter}%
          \@ifstar{%
            \toks@\expandafter{\the\toks@*}%
            \final@chapter
          }{\next@chapter}%
        }
        \newcommand*{\final@chapter}[1]{%
          \the\toks@{#1}%
          \thispagestyle{empty}%
        }
        \newcommand*{\next@chapter}{%
          \@ifnextchar[{\opt@chapter}{\final@chapter}%
        }
        \newcommand*{\opt@chapter}{}%
        \def\opt@chapter[#1]{%
          \toks@\expandafter{\the\toks@[{#1}]}%
          \final@chapter
        }%
        \wlog{* Chapter redefined.}%
      }%
    \else
      % KOMA-Script classes
      \renewcommand*{\chapterpagestyle}{empty}%
      \wlog{* Chapter page style set by redefining \string\chapterpagestyle.}%
    \fi
  }%
\fi
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter*{Chapter with star}
\chapter{Chapter without optional argument}
\chapter[Chapter's optional argument]{Chapter with optional argument}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 7):

Your use of arguments are not optimal, since `\chapter{<stuff>}` defaults to `\chapter[<stuff>]{<stuff>}` in the absence of an optional argument, not `\chapter[]{<stuff>}`. It's better to patch `\chapter` using [`etoolbox`](http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox):

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{etoolbox}% http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox
\patchcmd{\chapter}% <cmd>
  {plain}% <search>
  {empty}% <replace>
  {}{}% <success><failure>
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{Bla Bla}
Some text ...
\newpage
\chapter{Bla Bla}
\end{document}
```

This searches for `plain` in `\chapter` and changes it to `empty`. The original definition of `\chapter` in [`book.cls`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/unpacked/book.cls) is:

```
\newcommand\chapter{\if@openright\cleardoublepage\else\clearpage\fi
                    \thispagestyle{plain}%
                    \global\@topnum\z@
                    \@afterindentfalse
                    \secdef\@chapter\@schapter}
```