# Redefine \chapter to add \printMiniToc

Tags: macros, chapters, koma-script, etoolbox

I want every chapter to have `\printMiniToc` after it. However I don't want to have to add `\printMiniToc` after every `\chapter`.

So I tried using `etoolbox` and tried this:

```
xapptocmd{\chapter}{\printMiniToc}{\message{** patching of \string\chapter succeeded **}}{\message{** patching of \string\chapter failed **}}
```

However that's resulted in this message:

```
Argument of \select@group has an extra }.
Paragraph ended before \select@group was
```

Which appears about 50 times.

NB: I've seen [Problem‎ with redefining \chapter{...} command‎](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/73242/problem-with-redefining-chapter-command) seems to be about changing the style and so the answers seem to be along the line of:

```
\RequirePackage{etoolbox}[2010/09/12]%
 \patchcmd{\chapter}{plain}{empty}{%
   \wlog{* Chapter patched by \string\patchcmd.}%
 }{%
```

Which I can't see applying in this case.

NB2: I'm also using KOMA-script

NB3: This is `\printMiniToc`

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\printMiniToc}{
    \vfill
    \hspace*{3.2cm}\parbox[t]{\textwidth-4cm}{
    \hspace*{-5mm}\raisebox{0.25mm}{\fontsize{0.6cm}{1ex}\selectfont    \color{contrastColour}\faList}
        \hspace*{5.5mm} {\huge{Summary}}
        \vspace*{2mm}
        \startcontents[chapters]
        \hypersetup{linkcolor=black}
        \begin{spacing}{1}
            \printcontents[chapters]{p}{1}{\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}}
        \end{spacing}
    }
    \vfill
    \newpage
}
\makeatother
```

Comment: What package or setup do you use to produce `\printMiniToc`? Can you provide a minimal example?

Comment: I added the info :)

Comment: So you're using [this template](https://github.com/HarveySheppard/yLaTeX/blob/master/examples/TM/config.tex)...

Comment: Yep! Don't tell me you got that just from a google search?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can update `\scr@@startchapter` to append `\printMiniToc`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{titletoc}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\printMiniToc}{
  \startcontents[chapters]
  \printcontents[chapters]{p}{1}{\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}}
}

\let\oldscr@@startchapter\scr@@startchapter
\def\scr@@startchapter#1[#2]#3{%
  \oldscr@@startchapter{#1}[#2]{#3}%
  \printMiniToc
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\sloppy
\chapter{A chapter}\lipsum[1-10]
\section{First section}\lipsum[11-20]
\section{Second section}\lipsum[21-30]
\section{Third section}\lipsum[31-40]
\section{Last section}\lipsum[41-50]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Worked like a charm :)

Answer (score 2):

Avoid patching internal and undocumented KOMA-Script commands. So here is a suggestion patching `\chapterlinesformat`:

```
\usepackage{xpatch}
\xapptocmd{\chapterlinesformat}{%
  \ifstr{#1}{chapter}{\ifstr{#2}{}{}{%
    \par\chapterheadendvskip
    \normalfont\normalsize\printMiniToc
    \vspace{-\baselineskip}%
}}{}}{}{\PatchFailed}
```

[image]

If option `chapterprefix` is set, `\chapterlineswithprefix` must be patched in the same way:

```
\usepackage{xpatch}
\xapptocmd{\chapterlinesformat}{%
  \ifstr{#1}{chapter}{\ifstr{#2}{}{}{%
    \par\chapterheadendvskip
    \normalfont\normalsize\printMiniToc
    \vspace{-\baselineskip}%
}}{}}{}{\PatchFailed}
```

[image]

Example which works with and without option `chapterprefix`:

```
\documentclass[
  %chapterprefix
]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{titletoc}

\newcommand{\printMiniToc}{
  \startcontents[chapters]
  \printcontents[chapters]{p}{1}{\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}}
}
\newcommand{\addMiniTocToChapter}[2]{%
  \ifstr{#1}{chapter}{\ifstr{#2}{}{}{%
    \par\chapterheadendvskip
    \normalfont\normalsize\printMiniToc
    \vspace{-\baselineskip}%
  }}{}%
}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\xapptocmd{\chapterlinesformat}{\addMiniTocToChapter{#1}{#2}}{}{\PatchFailed}
\xapptocmd{\chapterlineswithprefixformat}{\addMiniTocToChapter{#1}{#2}}{}{\PatchFailed}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{A chapter}\lipsum[1-5]
\section{First section}\lipsum[6-10]
\section{Second section}\lipsum[11-15]
\section{Third section}\lipsum[16-20]
\section{Last section}\lipsum[21-25]
\end{document}
```

Comment: For some reason with my document, this doesn't seem to successfully prepend `\printMiniToc` — though I can see it clearly works in yours. The full 'context' of my excerpt can be found here https://github.com/tecosaur/mgdt/blob/master/mgdt.cls if that's of any use.

Comment: Note the warnings regarding the usage of package `titlesec` together with a KOMA-Script class. This package breaks some of the KOMA possibilities (option settings etc.)